How to run a python function on a separate terminal
Lets say that I have a python file, main.py:
import module
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_in_a_new_terminal(module.run(arg1, arg2))

and module.py, in the same directory, is:
def run(options: list):
    print(i for i in options)

Currently, I'm trying to run main.py and somehow get run() in module.py to run in a seperate terminal window. I would need to do this, since using sys.argv wouldn't work, the options list contains a custom data type. I thought of encoding it and then decoding it in the module.py, but I doubt it would work.
How would I run module.run() in a new terminal instance?

I tried using subprocess, but I couldn't run the FUNCTION in a new terminal, only commands in a new terminal

I tried using multiprocessing.Process, but I can't get it to run it in a new terminal
p = Process(target=module.run, args=(options, ))


Of course, I tried os.system() but: 1) cross-platform is a nightmare & 2) I want to run the function and I can't do that with os.system(), as far as I know.


P.S. I also tried searching for a way to run the function via the terminal, but all I could find was sys.argv (which doesn't work because the options list contains custom data types) and doing python -c (code), which isn't particularly efficient since module.py could reach hundreds of lines in some cases.
P.P.S. I'm making a metasploit-like penetration software like routersploit and I'm trying to run the module in a new terminal when I enter the "run" command. I'm trying to open it in a new terminal because it's easier to control everything at once if you're running multiple modules at once. This isn't a huge project, I just want a minimalistic program that can function like metasploit. Anyways, the main reason I need to run the function in a new terminal is that I need to input the options into the program, but I want minimal changes to the modules since there's thousands of modules out there and changing them to fit my program individually would be a pain. So, I decided to have a run() function that runs the modules with the options list in it.
Here's the full code for the main program (suggestions are very welcome)

this sounds like an XY Problem .. what exactly are you trying to accomplish? it's probably easiest to communicate here to a completely different shell via a socket, but not necessarily

I don't think there's a OS-agnostic way to do this. What OS are you using?



How do I run a function from another module/library/file in a new terminal/command prompt?


I'm trying to get it to run in linux & windows



Programs don't usually open new terminal windows. There are a million terminal emulators; you might not even be in a graphical environment; and as a user I expect to control my own terminal windows, I don't want you opening new ones for me. So what is your underlying goal? We can likely suggest ways to accomplish it without opening new windows.

This is not a good practice.  It's mixing the console/GUI paradigm.  What if you're logged in through ssh?  You CAN do this using start in Windows or something like xterm in Linux, but it will always be unexpected.

This program is meant to be completely graphical. It shouldn't be able to be run via ssh anyways

The simple and obvious solution is to use xterm -e python main.py & to run the script. Though if it is completely graphical, why do you need a terminal at all?
